# Signal R - Handling a disconnect outside of a hub

Tags: c#, sockets, signalr, instance, signalr-hub

I am trying to accomplish sending data to my client methods from a controller method that returns a response when the instance client is disconnected.

**Controller**
Currently..

```
 public void SomeMethod(){
    IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    while(true){
         hubContext.Clients.All.addNameValue(name,value);
    }
 }
```

What I would like..

```
 bool someProperty = false
 public string SomeMethod(){
    IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    while(true & (someProperty == false)){
         hubContext.Clients.All.addNameValue(name,value);
    }
    return "done";
 }
```

since we know a client disconnects from the hub overrided method..

**Hub**

```
 public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled = true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hub Disconnected: {0}\n", Context.ConnectionId);
        return (base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled));
    }
```

Is there any way from outside a hub to keep track of a controller instance so that something like this can be done?

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled = true)
    {
        SomeClass.someProperty = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Hub OnDisconnected {0}\n", Context.ConnectionId);
        return (base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled));
    }
```

We seek the ability to open a connection using signal R when we want to stream data back and forth, but the ability to know when the client disconnects so the client can continue doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a hub that uses a singleton class to keep track of your clients, then if you need to you can store all of connected clients, to be able to reconnect when the server comes back online. There really is no disconnect event on the client, only a reconnected event. So its hard to determine if a server has been disconnected or not. The way that I work around this is to subscribe to the connection.closed event. For me I make one attempt to reconnect, it that fails, I notify the user and exit the application. For info on the singleton method of keeping track clients I developed mine from this link: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

```
       tcHubProxy(HubConnection hubConnection, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        mhubConn = hubConnection;
        mIHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("CentralHub");
        mWriter = writer;
        mWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        try
        {
            mhubConn.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
            mhubConn.TraceWriter = mWriter;
            mhubConn.Closed += MhubConnOnClosed;
            mhubConn.Start().Wait();
            LogEvent(DateTime.Now, "Info", "Client Connected");
            mIHubProxy.On<List<User>>("updateFmds", GetUserFmds);
            connected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (showMessage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "There is currently no connection to the server, this application will close, if this issue persists check your network connection or contact support.",
                    "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                showMessage = false;
            } 
            connected = false;
            showMessage = false;
        }
    }

 public void MhubConnOnClosed()
    {
        LogEvent(DateTime.Now, "Info", "Client connection to communication hub, attempting to redirect.");
        try
        {
            mhubConn = new HubConnection(ConnectionString);
            mhubConn.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
            mhubConn.TraceWriter = mWriter;
            mIHubProxy = mhubConn.CreateHubProxy("CentralHub");
            mhubConn.Start().Wait();
            LogEvent(DateTime.Now, "Info", "Reconnection successful.");
            mIHubProxy.On<List<User>>("updateFmds", GetUserFmds);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogEvent(DateTime.Now, "Error", "Reconnection attempt failed.", e.StackTrace, e.Message);
            if (showMessage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "There is currently no connection to the server, this application will close, if this issue persists check your network connection or contact support.",
                    "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                showMessage = false;
            }
            connected = false;
        }
    }
```